# Which one is executed?

Tags: windows, npm, cmd

Please,  how do I know which one of the available npm is executed when I do `npm` on cmd ?

e.g: npm init, npm install ...etc.

On windows, I'm executing : `where npm` and this is the output:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
```

which one is the corresponding file ?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a command in cmd, the command is searched in the current directory and than in the directories given in the path environment variable. The same is doing the 'where' command if no options are used.

So the first match found by the 'where' command is the one which is actually executed.

If the match is found in the current directory, be aware that the result changes if your current directory changes.